# Simulation of a LAN Network on the internet

Tags: web-development, simulation, lan

I'm developing a distributed system with a shared hashtable as a project for school. It's written using java Sockets. Since the simulation is required to run at least on two different PCs, is there any way to simulate a LAN over the Internet? It would be very useful since me and the other members of this project are not easy to meet together. If we can simulate staying at home it would make a big difference.

Anyway, I've 2 other questions:

1. If we're going to meet and connect our two PCs with Ethernet, we should find our addresses (IP) running a netconfig command on CMD (Windows), right?
2. Otherwise if we connect to the same wifi LAN does it work the same? (That is to say again running a netconfig on CMD to retrieve the IP)

Answer (score 0):

> simulate a LAN over the Internet

What you are describing is a VPN.

These days, most VPN's are used for different purposes than you are describing, but the core idea of a VPN is to connect computers over the Internet as if they were on the same LAN. [This old Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35701/best-way-to-create-a-vpn-between-two-windows-machines) is very relevant to your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community - I don't really think that VPN needs describing or citation.